# How can it be 63%?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I read a Comp. science article(below) about latency and I'm confused how he can state that 63% probability that there will be 1 second latency. Can you help me understand this?

> for example, consider a system where each server typically responds in
>   10ms but with a 99th-percentile latency of one second. If a user
>   request is handled on just one such server, one user request in 100
>   will be slow (one second). ... (skipped) ... If a user request must collect
>   responses from 100 such servers in parallel, then **63%** of user requests
>   will take more than one second.

P.S. I'm confused what to put as the title, because I'm not sure what is the correct term for this case, please help me edit the title. Thanks

**EDIT**

I will try to rephrase above article using non-IT term.

> For example, you send a message/email to someone, 99th-percentile of the time you
>   need to wait for 1 second, otherwise 10ms, to get the reply from that person. 
>   Now let's say you have 100 persons like that, then you send a message to all of them, then 63%  of the reply will come
>   after 1 second.

Hope my understanding is correct

Comment: I can't even understand the language: "latency of one second", "servers"...and I guess $\;10\;$ ms is ... $\;10\;$ miliseconds? This probaby doesn't fit mathematics but...something else: computer science or whatever.

Comment: Hmm.. Yes the topic is in comp. science, but then this computation I believe is about probability. ms is indeed a miliseconds. I will rephrase the article to be more general..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With each server, you have $99\%$ probability that it will answer with no latency. In other words, $0.99$ of the times it will answer with no latency.

Now what is the probability that all servers answer in time? This is $p = 0.99^{100}$. This is because the probability that two servers both answer in time will be $0.99 \times 0.99$ etc. (The two probabilities are assumed to be independent of each other.)

Compute $p$. Then $1 - p$ will be the probability that al least one server will have answered with a one second latency.

Translate back to percent notation, and you'll get the answer you were given.

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot. I know it should be that simple. Instead, I keep thinking the reverse, 0.1^100. BTW, what can you get the number without `1-p`? if so, how?

Comment: You're welcome. This is a standard argument, which you will encounter fairly often - the easy to compute probability is that of the complementary event (in this case, all servers answer in time), so you go for it.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* Whenever you see $63\%$ you could think of an exponentially distributed scenario, since

\begin{align*}
1-e^{-\lambda}\simeq 63\%
\end{align*}

when setting $\lambda=1$.

> In this scenario we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> 0.99^{100}=\left(1-\frac{1}{100}\right)^{100}
> \simeq  e^{-1}
> \end{align*}
>   since
>   \begin{align*}
> \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=e^{-1}
> \end{align*}